# Mongoose: How to call Model#save on docs returned by resolved Promise.all()?

Tags: mongoose, bluebird

I have the following code which uses Mongoose and Bluebird as mongoose's promise provider. What I am trying to achieve is to call `Model#save` on each of the elements of the array of mongoose docs returned when `Promise.all()` resolves, as illustrated below. This code is not working, and my guess is that when I call `doc.save()`, I am not doing it on an object recognized as an instance of a Mongoose Model. How can I fix this?

```
promises = [
  User.findById(userId).exec(),
  Post.findById(postId).exec()
];

var promisedDocs = Promise.all(promises)  // Should resolve to [{ user: {} }, {post: {} }]
  .then(function(results) {
    results.map(function(result) {
      // Extract the first property of object in array element.
      var doc = result[Object.keys(result)[0]];
      doc.someArrayProp.push(someValue);
      doc.save();
   });
});
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK       So, ignoring the first line of the function provided to results.map(), the doc.save() call should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promise returned by `Promise.all` will resolve to `[user, post]`, so you can directly operate on the documents in your `results.map` callback:

```js
var promisedDocs = Promise.all(promises)  // Resolves to [user, post]
  .then(function(results) {
    results.map(function(doc) {
      doc.someArrayProp.push(someValue);
      doc.save();
   });
});
```